# My Http request is not firing anymore after I started pulling data in from a reactive form observable stream

Tags: angular, rxjs, hubspot

I have an Angular app (v17) in an Nx Monorepo. This component is in a library I created. For some reason, when I submit my form, the Http request does not fire. Everything was working until I tried to use a SwitchMap to get the reactive form's data stream into the request. I've poured over docs and examples and can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong. I should mention as well that this is an SSR/SSG Angular app.

```js
export class SignupFormComponent {
  http = inject(HttpClient);
  fb = inject(FormBuilder);

  headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
  portalId = 'dummy';
  formId = 'dummy';

  signUpForm = this.fb.group({
    firstName: ['', [Validators.required]],
    lastName: ['', [Validators.required]],
    email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
    company: ['', [Validators.required]],
  });

  dataObject$ = this.signUpForm.valueChanges.pipe(
    debounceTime(500),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    map((val) =>
      Object.keys(val).map((key) => ({
        objectTypeId: '0-1',
        name: key.toLowerCase(),
        value: val[key as keyof typeof val],
      })),
    ),
  );

  req = this.dataObject$.pipe(
    switchMap((data) => {
      const url = `https://api.hsforms.com/submissions/v3/integration/submit/${this.portalId}/${this.formId}`;
      return this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(data), {
        headers: this.headers,
      });
    }),
  );

  submitForm() {
    return this.req.subscribe(console.log);
  }
}
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="signUpForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
  <label for="first-name" class="text-white">First Name</label>
  <input id="first-name" type="text" formControlName="firstName" />
  <label for="last-name" class="text-white">Last Name</label>
  <input id="last-name" type="text" formControlName="lastName" />
  <label for="email" class="text-white">Email</label>
  <input id="email" type="text" formControlName="email" />
  <label for="company" class="text-white">Company</label>
  <input id="company" type="text" formControlName="company" />
  <button type="submit">
    Join Now
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Does the http request fire if you click the button, then change the value in one of the form fields?

Comment: First of all, you're mixing imperative programming and reactive programming. This is usually not a good idea. Remember that as soon as you `subscribe`, the reactivity ends. Here, you subscribe in the `submitForm` method. What if that method is called again? Well, you have no more control over that and it'd create a race condition. Second, your stream is based of `signUpForm.valueChanges` which does not emit when subscribed to, you'd need a `startWith` and the form current value. I'll create a demo to clarify all that up.

Comment: It is not a reason why your code doesn't work, but: Never use switchMap() for non-GET requests. Use exhaustMap() if you don't know which one to use, or check their descriptions.

Answer (score 1):

As explained [in my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77916899/my-http-request-is-not-firing-anymore-after-i-started-pulling-data-in-from-a-rea/77917562?noredirect=1#comment137367312_77916899), you have a couple of things that prevent it to work well:

- Mixing imperative and reactive programming
- Listening to a stream based of a form `valueChanges`, which does not emit when subscribed to (you'd need a `startWith` with the current form value)

That said, your code isn't handling any error as well so I have made you a detailed example that should be fairly robust with error handling and display of the current status in the UI.

I've made a live demo with a mock server but before, let's have a look to the code.

```js
interface HttpCallSuccess<Data> {
  type: 'success';
  data: Data;
}
interface HttpCallError {
  type: 'error';
  error: String;
}
interface HttpCallSending {
  type: 'sending';
}
type HttpCallState<Data> =
  | HttpCallSending
  | HttpCallSuccess<Data>
  | HttpCallError;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="signUpForm" (ngSubmit)="submitButtonClicked$$.next()">
      <label for="first-name" class="text-white">First Name</label>
      <input id="first-name" type="text" formControlName="firstName" /><br />

      <label for="last-name" class="text-white">Last Name</label>
      <input id="last-name" type="text" formControlName="lastName" /><br />

      <button type="submit" [disabled]="submitButtonDisabled$ | async" >Join Now</button>
    </form>

    <p>{{ textSummary$ | async }}</p>
  `,
  imports: [CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
})
export class App {
  private readonly http = inject(HttpClient);
  private readonly fb = inject(FormBuilder);
  private readonly destroyRef = inject(DestroyRef);

  public readonly submitButtonClicked$$ = new Subject<void>();

  public readonly signUpForm = this.fb.group({
    firstName: ['', [Validators.required]],
    lastName: ['', [Validators.required]],
  });

  private readonly formattedValues$ = this.signUpForm.valueChanges.pipe(
    map((val) =>
      (Object.keys(val) as Array<keyof typeof val>).map((key) => ({
        objectTypeId: '0-1',
        name: key.toLowerCase(),
        value: val[key],
      }))
    )
  );

  private readonly sendFormToServerSideEffect$: Observable<
    HttpCallState<void>
  > = this.submitButtonClicked$$.pipe(
    withLatestFrom(this.formattedValues$),
    switchMap(([_, data]) => {
      const httpCall$ = this.http.post<void>(`https://your-api.com`, data).pipe(
        map((res): HttpCallSuccess<void> => ({ type: 'success', data: res })),
        catchError((e: Error): Observable<HttpCallError> => {
          console.error(e); // should be a proper logger instead
          return of({ type: 'error', error: e.message });
        })
      );

      return concat(of({ type: 'sending' as const }), httpCall$);
    }),
    shareReplay({ refCount: true, bufferSize: 1 })
  );

  public readonly submitButtonDisabled$ = this.signUpForm.statusChanges.pipe(
    startWith(this.signUpForm.status),
    switchMap((status) => {
      if (status === 'INVALID') {
        return of(true);
      }
      return concat(
        of(false), // unlock the submit button when form becomes valid
        this.sendFormToServerSideEffect$.pipe(
          map((requestState) => {
            return {
              sending: true,
              success: true,
              error: false, // let the user retry if there's an error
            }[requestState.type];
          })
        )
      );
    })
  );

  public readonly textSummary$: Observable<string> =
    this.sendFormToServerSideEffect$.pipe(
      map((httpCallState) => {
        switch (httpCallState.type) {
          case 'success':
            return 'Thanks for registering';
          case 'error':
            return `Something went wrong: "${httpCallState.error}". You can retry`;
          case 'sending':
            return `Please wait while we're processing your request`;
        }
      })
    );

  constructor() {
    this.sendFormToServerSideEffect$
      .pipe(takeUntilDestroyed(this.destroyRef))
      .subscribe();
  }
}
```

Key points of the code:

- No subscribe within methods. When you subscribe, reactivity ends. I only subscribe from the `constructor` and use a `takeUntilDestroyed` to make sure it's all cleaned up when the component is destroyed to avoid memory leaks
- Actions from the view are bound to subjects instead of calling a method. Remember that we're in a reactive world and therefore we want to signal an event that some stream can react to. To make sure that we avoid any confusion, I call this one `submitButtonClicked$$` which really suggests it's an **event** and **not an action** (like sendForm or something similar)
- I use `shareReplay({ refCount: true, bufferSize: 1 })` on streams that shouldn't be subscribed more than once
- I try as much as possible to keep it close to a stream that represents a state machine, easier to reason about

In the demo you'll also see that I'm calling for real `http.post` but I have created a mock version of `HttpClient` like this:

```js
@Injectable()
class MockHttpClient {
  private count = 0;
  public post() {
    this.count++;

    if (this.count === 1) {
      return timer(2000).pipe(
        switchMap(() =>
          throwError(() => new Error(`Some error from the mock server`))
        )
      );
    }

    return of({ status: 'ok' }).pipe(delay(2000));
  }
}
```

To be able to throw an error the first time, and succeed after. So do try it out in Stackblitz and you'll see the text changing and the submit button being enabled/disabled based on the status.

Here's the [Stackblitz live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-mvygr1?file=src%2Fmain.ts).

Answer (score 0):

The `valueChanges` is a good option when we subscribe to it during the form initialization, since we have `distinctUntilChanged` present and there are no value changes after the form is submitted the `POST` is never called, to simplify this use case, we can just manually contruct the request object using the same logic you wrote and then call the api!

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {
  HttpClient,
  HttpHeaders,
  provideHttpClient,
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, ReactiveFormsModule, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {
  distinctUntilChanged,
  debounceTime,
  map,
  switchMap,
  BehaviorSubject,
} from 'rxjs';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, CommonModule],
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="signUpForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
      <label for="first-name" class="text-white">First Name</label>
      <input id="first-name" type="text" formControlName="firstName" />
      <label for="last-name" class="text-white">Last Name</label>
      <input id="last-name" type="text" formControlName="lastName" />
      <label for="email" class="text-white">Email</label>
      <input id="email" type="text" formControlName="email" />
      <label for="company" class="text-white">Company</label>
      <input id="company" type="text" formControlName="company" />
      <button type="submit">
        Join Now
      </button>
    </form>
  `,
})
export class App {
  formObjectSubject: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  http = inject(HttpClient);
  fb = inject(FormBuilder);

  headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
  portalId = 'dummy';
  formId = 'dummy';

  signUpForm = this.fb.group({
    firstName: ['', [Validators.required]],
    lastName: ['', [Validators.required]],
    email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
    company: ['', [Validators.required]],
  });

  constructData() {
    return Object.keys(this.signUpForm.controls).map((key) => {
      const val = this.signUpForm.controls;
      return {
        objectTypeId: '0-1',
        name: key.toLowerCase(),
        value: val[key as keyof typeof val].value,
      };
    });
  }

  submitForm() {
    const data = this.constructData();
    console.log(data);
    const url = `https://api.hsforms.com/submissions/v3/integration/submit/${this.portalId}/${this.formId}`;
    this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(data), {
      headers: this.headers,
    }).subscribe();
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [provideHttpClient()],
});
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-22pmnj?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)

Comment: You're never subscribing to the observable, are you ? I don't see how that can possibly work

Comment: As mentioned in my comment on the original post, I don't think that having a subscribe in a method is a good idea. From there, you completely lose control over your stream and you cannot decide if it's called again whether the previous stream should be cancelled (switchMap), if the new one should be skipped (exhaustMap), if they should be queued up (concatMap), etc. I've added a detailed answer that shows how to achieve this

Comment: @maxime1992 I think mine is the imperative style, while your is reactive style, anyway its up to the person who asked the question, thanks again for noticing the missing subscribe!

Comment: Yours is indeed **a mix** of imperative style and some reactive style. But as I said, you completely lose the ability to manage what to do if the `submitForm` method is called multiple times and you therefore `subscribe` multiple times to the stream there. That's what I really don't like here. Otherwise... Up to you what style you prefer, sure. But by doing that kind of mix, you'll always end up losing control over your streams and sooner or later, create race condition. If you don't disable the submit button which would be a quick dirty hack, you can't prevent the call to be sent twice for ex

Comment: @maxime1992 I disable the button, or just unsubscribe the previous subscription and call a fresh one to solve that issue!

Comment: "I disable the button" as I said, I know this can solve it. But in more complex scenario the UI won't be able to be locked to prevent further actions. "unsubscribe the previous subscription and call a fresh one" does this not sound to you like it should be managed by a switchMap? Plus, I'm curious to know how you do that. You'll keep an extra class field "subscription" and you'll call unsubscribe every time when that method is called? May as well not use rxjs at all at this stage

Comment: `if(this.subscription) {this.subscription.unsubscribe()}
this.subscription = this.service.apicall().subscribe();` like this, I use RXJS for the big work, like chaining API calls, convert array to observables, debounceTime events and api caching, whichever gives the least code and least maintenance, I choose that basically!