# Angular call one api after another

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have below code where I am calling one api after another but the other api call is happenning inside subscribe.  Can we use merge map in this case to avoid multiple subscribe.

Below is my code

```
  saveEmployees(empObject: any) {
    from(
      this.empService.saveEmployees(empObject)
    ).subscribe(
      (res) => {
        try {
          
          this.getOfficeInfo();
          this.stopLoading(false);
        }
        catch (error) {
          this.setLoadingFlags(false);
          this.toastr.error("Error Saving Employees...");
        }
      }
    )
  }
  
  
  getOfficeInfo() {
    this.empService.getOfficeInfo().subscribe(
      (res: any) => {
        if (res != null) {
          this.RowData = res.data;

        } else {
         //
        }
      },
      (err) => {
        var test = "err";
      }
    );
  }
```

Tried to refactor the above code to below, errors out with

Property pipe does not exist on type Promise any[] and
Type void is not assignable to type ObservableInput

```
this.empService
  .saveEmployees(empObject)
  .pipe(
    mergeMap((res: any) => {
      return this.getOfficeInfo()
    })
  ).subscribe((res: any) => {
        //get office info here and assign to grid
  });
```

Comment: I have answered a very similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77919195/2398593 where I also took the time to explain how to make the code fully reactive instead of a mix reactive/imperative programming

Answer (score 1):

Since we do not need to data from the first observable, we can go with [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) Once the intial observable completes (save is completed) we switch to the inner observable which refreshes the data and that is finally obtained in the subscribe.

The loading methods are a bit confusing, but basically, we can start the loading indicator on the first line of `saveEmployees` and the loading can be stopped on the `next` and `error` function first line!

We need to use `from` because `saveEmployees` is returning a promise, so we can convert it to an observable using from!

```
  saveEmployees(empObject: any) {
    from(this.empService.saveEmployees(empObject))
      .pipe(switchMap(() => this.empService.getOfficeInfo()))
      .subscribe({
        next: (res: any) => {
          this.stopLoading(false);
          if (res != null) {
            this.RowData = res.data;
          } else {
            //
          }
        },
        error: (err) => {
          this.setLoadingFlags(false);
          this.toastr.error('Error Saving Employees...');
        },
      });
  }
```