# Angular: Multiple RxJS streams with independent loaders, but combined in a single view model stream

Tags: angular, rxjs

Let's say we have a dashboard component with a button and some subcomponents that show different data sources that are loaded asynchronously. When clicking on the button, the parent will fetch each source data concurrently, and once loaded, provide it to the children components. While loading, each subcomponent, will show an overlay loader. If there's an error in any of the sources load, a popup with an error message will be displayed over the subcomponent that had the error, and the loader will stop as well.

I was wondering how to do this elegantly, using a single view model stream that combines all the sub streams. I was thinking of something like this:

```
  combineLatest({
    data1: source1$,
    data2: source2$,
    ...
  });
  
  // Each source would have something like this
  source1$ = clickEvent$.pipe(
    switchMap(() => getData(parameters))
      .pipe(
         map((data) => ({ data, loading: false })),
         catchError((error) => of({ error, loading: false })),
         startWith({ error: null, loading: true }),
      ),
  );
```

The problem I have with this is that if there's an error, I'd like to be able to keep the last loaded data, while showing the popup message, but I have no way to access the last data from the catchError operator.

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77919195/2398593 where I have answered a similar question I believe. Let me know if you think that's enough or if you have further questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used @maxime1992 answer but fixed some typing errors and improved it a bit to be more specific for the question I asked: replaced the `type` property for type guards, and changed the RxJS operator to just return a `Result` object. Here's what I got:

Result interfaces and type guards:

```
interface ResultPending {
  loading: true;
}

interface ResultSuccess<T> {
  loading: false;
  payload: T;
}

interface ResultError {
  loading: false;
  error: any;
}

export type Result<T> = ResultPending | ResultSuccess<T> | ResultError;

export const isResultPending = <T>(
  result: Result<T>
): result is ResultPending => {
  return result.loading === true;
};

export const isResultSuccess = <T>(
  result: Result<T>
): result is ResultSuccess<T> => {
  return (
    result.loading === false &&
    (result as ResultSuccess<T>).payload !== undefined
  );
};
```

RxJS operator:

```
export const keepLastValidResult = <T>() => {
  let lastSuccessPayload = undefined as T;
  return function (source: Observable<Result<T>>): Observable<Result<T>> {
    return source.pipe(
      map((result) => {
        if (isResultSuccess(result)) {
          lastSuccessPayload = result.payload;
          return result;
        }
        if (isResultPending(result)) {
          return result;
        }
        return { ...result, payload: lastSuccessPayload };
      })
    );
  };
};
```

and finally, it would be used this way in the sources combined stream:

```
combineLatest({
  data1: source1$.pipe(keepLastValidResult()),
  data2: source2$.pipe(keepLastValidResult()),
});
```

Here you have a [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-alh9wx?devToolsHeight=33&file=src%2Ftest-rxjs-operator%2Ftest-rxjs-operator.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to accumulate values for each individual stream and keep the last successful one as well as the current value. Then you can decide what to do downstream, if you want to use the current one based on the type (pending, success, error) or use the last valid one.

Here's how that can be achieved.

First of all, we define our data structure for a result:

```js
interface ResultPending {
  type: 'pending';
  loading: true;
}

interface ResultSuccess<Data> {
  type: 'success';
  loading: false;
  data: Data;
}

interface ResultError {
  type: 'error';
  loading: false;
  error: any;
}

type Result<Data> = ResultPending | ResultSuccess<Data> | ResultError;
```

Then we create a generic function to describe a stream as a result using the previously built interface:

```js
function keepLastValidResult<Data>(): Observable<{
  lastValidResult: ResultSuccess<Data>;
  lastResult: Result<Data>;
}> {
  return (obs$: Observable<Data>) =>
    obs$.pipe(
      scan((acc, curr) => {
        switch (curr.type) {
          case 'success':
            return {
              lastValidResult: curr,
              lastResult: curr,
            };

          case 'pending':
          case 'error':
            return {
              ...acc,
              lastResult: curr,
            };
        }

        return acc;
      })
    );
}
```

And now, we can apply this custom operator to individual streams:

```js
combineLatest({
  data1: source1$.pipe(keepLastValidResult()),
  data2: source2$.pipe(keepLastValidResult()),
});
```

Then in your combine latest, you can check the type of the current result to know if it's a success or not, and if not use instead the `lastValidResult` to keep displaying the last valid result as the name suggests, but also display the error or loading state based on `lastResult`.

Comment: Nice! I think this could be simplified dropping the type from the Results interfaces and adding type guards to differentiate the types. Also, `keepLastValidResult` instead of returning both results, can just return one Result<Data> object: in the situation described in the question there's no need for those two objects. @maxime1992 If you agree I'll edit the question to add that

Comment: "I think this could be simplified dropping the type from the Results interfaces and adding type guards to differentiate the types", you can, but I always find it pretty error prone to have type guards without a discriminant that can be used as the only reliable value to differentiate them. It'll work in this case for sure, but overall I wouldn't recommend it. The extra "type" property isn't much to add and will make your life so much easier and your code a lot more robust in case new keys are added that could mix up the previous type guards

Answer (score 1):

The typical way to handle this would be to use `scan` as @maxime1992 has suggested.  Sometimes, it can be simpler to pass data from the template to the controller, rather than trying to keep track of it in the controller.

Instead of emitting void from your `clickEvent$`, you could pass the existing view model, which would represent your existing data:

```js
  combineLatest({
    data1: source1$,
    data2: source2$,
    ...
  });
  
  source1$ = clickEvent$.pipe(
    switchMap(existing => getData(parameters).pipe(
       map(data => ({ data, loading: false })),
       catchError(error => of({ data: existing.data1, error, loading: false })),
       startWith({ error: null, loading: true }),
    ),
  );
```