# How to Retrieve an Array at the End of an Observable Without Using toArray() in Angular/RxJS?

Tags: rxjs, reactive, declarative, angular-signals

I have an observable enriched_sns$ which I'm enriching by performing operations on each emitted item using concatMap, and then combining the results into an array using toArray(). However, I'm curious if there's an alternative approach to achieve the same result without using toArray().

Here's my current code:

```
private enriched_sns$ = toObservable(this.sn_results).pipe(
  concatMap((results) => results as StreamNotificationResult[]),
  concatMap((notification) => {
    const user_id = notification.activities[0].actor.id;
    return zip(of(notification), this.read_user_data_service.readUserData(user_id));
  }),
  map(([notification, user]) => {
    return {
      notification,
      user: user,
    };
  }),
  toArray(),
);
```

Is there a way to obtain an array of emitted items at the end of the observable without resorting to toArray()? Any help or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What's the issue with `toArray`? What are you trying to go around here?

Comment: I'm trying to move towards a more declarative approach without needing to manually subscribe, and I want to make the most of Angular's Signals features.

Comment: I don't understand your issue with using `toArray`.  Is it providing the functionality you need or are you looking for different behavior?

Comment: I really wished the Angular team was a lot more explicit as to what are Signals for. Observables are perfectly fine @syahiruddin please have a look into a similar answer I've made here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78100064/2398593

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you need to use `toArray()` in your example is because you are taking the emitted array from your signal and then emitting each element individually.

You could use the `forkJoin` function to handle subscribing to an array of observables, rather than using `concatMap` to emit each element one at a time:

```js
private enriched_sns$ = toObservable(this.sn_results).pipe(
  concatMap((results: StreamNotificationResult[]) => forkJoin(
    results.map(n => this.read_user_data_service.readUserData(n.activities[0].actor.id).pipe(
      map(user => ({ notification: n, user }))
    ))
  )),
);
```

There is one important difference `forkJoin` will subscribe to all observables at the same time, not one at a time.  If you need to limit concurrency, you could check out the [`rxjs-etc`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs-etc) package that has a [`forkJoinConcurrent`](https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-etc/blob/main/source/observable/forkJoinConcurrent.ts) function which allows you to specify concurrency:

```js
private enriched_sns$ = toObservable(this.sn_results).pipe(
  concatMap((results: StreamNotificationResult[]) => forkJoinConcurrent(
    results.map(n=> this.read_user_data_service.readUserData(n.activities[0].actor.id).pipe(
      map(user => ({ notification: n, user }))
    ))
  ), 1), // <-- limit to one inner subscription at a time
);
```

---

Note, use of `zip`/`of` is not necessary at all. You can simply add a `.pipe` to your inner observable and map the emission to your desired shape:

```js
private enriched_sns$ = toObservable(this.sn_results).pipe(
  concatMap((results: StreamNotificationResult[]) => results),
  concatMap(notification => {
    const user_id = notification.activities[0].actor.id;
    return this.read_user_data_service.readUserData(user_id).pipe(
      map(user => ({ notification, user }))
    );
  }),
  toArray(),
);
```

Comment: Thans, @BizzyBob. Your initial response mentioning, "You can simply add a .pipe to your inner observable and map the emission to your desired shape" does it. However, I am still unsure why `forkJoin` did not return anything, while `zip` worked for me. Nevertheless, thank you very much for your help. Cheers!